# Set DateTime SONY SDK

Tags: c++, sdk, sony

I am trying to set the datetime of a Sony RX0 II using the Sony SDK. Without modifying too much to the *RemoteCli.cpp* code that is provided as an example, I added a case there and create a new function in *CameraDevice.cpp* like this one

```
void CameraDevice::set_datetime()
{
    // Set the new date at 1970/01/01
    CrInt64 newdate = 0;

    SDK::CrDeviceProperty prop;
    prop.SetCode(SDK::CrDevicePropertyCode::CrDeviceProperty_DateTime_Settings);
    prop.SetCurrentValue(newdate);
    prop.SetValueType(SDK::CrDataType::CrDataType_UInt64);

    auto err = SDK::SetDeviceProperty(m_device_handle, &prop);
    
    if (CR_FAILED(err)) {
        tout << "Failed to set new date path.\n";

}
```

I do not get any error, so it should work but I never got the new time written on the camera

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. Turns out the camera just ignores invalid values and gives no errors. The valid ranges differ from camera to camera.

To check the valid values for your camera, go into the settings menu on the camera and check the earliest and latest values that you can set. Mine did not allow dates before 2021, so 0 is not a valid value.