# Set current DateTime - SONY SDK

Tags: c++, sdk, sony

I am trying to set the datetime of a Sony alpha 7s iii to be a PC current datetime, using the Sony SDK.
Without modifying too much to the RemoteCli.cpp code that is provided as an example, I added a case there:

```
while (true) {
    cli::tout << "<< Time Sync >>\nWhat would you like to do? Enter the corresponding number.\n";
    cli::tout
        << "(0) Return to REMOTE-MENU\n"
        << "(1) Set Camera Time From PC \n"
        ;
    cli::tout << "input> ";
    cli::text select;
    std::getline(cli::tin, select);
    cli::tout << '\n';
    if (select == TEXT("1")) { /* Time Sync */
        camera->set_datetime();
    }
    else if (select == TEXT("0")) {
        cli::tout << "Return to REMOTE-MENU.\n";
        break;
    }
    cli::tout << std::endl;
}// end of loop-Menu7
```

and [based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71208824/set-datetime-sony-sdk)
, I created a new `set_datetime` function in CameraDevice.cpp:

```
void CameraDevice::set_datetime() {
    std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
    std::asctime(std::localtime(&result));
    cli::tout << result;

    CrInt64 time = static_cast<CrInt64>(result);
    SDK::CrDeviceProperty prop;
    prop.SetCode(SDK::CrDevicePropertyCode::CrDeviceProperty_DateTime_Settings);
    prop.SetCurrentValue(time);
    prop.SetValueType(SDK::CrDataType::CrDataType_UInt64);
}
```

Unfortunately, the PC current time is not written on the camera.

Comment: Run a debugger and check if the function gets called at all.

Comment: I checked - `set_datetime` function gets called. The problem is that according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77088777/19376002) if the value isn't valid, the camera ignores it and gives no errors.
I'm new to C++ and was thinking this might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't notice that I forgot to add the set device property command -  `SDK::SetDeviceProperty(m_device_handle, &prop);`

Changed it to this:

```
void CameraDevice::set_datetime() {
    std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
    std::asctime(std::localtime(&result));
    cli::tout << result;

    SDK::CrDeviceProperty prop;
    prop.SetCode(SDK::CrDevicePropertyCode::CrDeviceProperty_DateTime_Settings);
    prop.SetCurrentValue((CrInt64u)(result));
    prop.SetValueType(SDK::CrDataType::CrDataType_UInt64);

    SDK::SetDeviceProperty(m_device_handle, &prop);
}
```

And it worked!

In addition, when looking at the datetime on the camera's screen (in settings), it won't work.

The camera settings menu needs to be closed.